# Flutter: Checkbox Tristate won't work on Null Safety

Tags: flutter, checkbox, dart-null-safety

How can I archive `tristate` for checkbox with nullsafety.... i have to pass null into that value but nullsafety has to perform null check on a variable, this is just contradicting .....

Putting null check as usual:

```
                 bool? parentvalue;

                 void update() {
                     parentvalue = null;
                  }


                 Checkbox(
                      ....
                      value: parentvalue!,
                  onChanged: update(),
                      ....
                    ),
```

> ERROR: Null check operator used on a null value

if I remove null check, code cannot compile at all

```
                  bool parentvalue;

                  void update() {
                    parentvalue = null;
                    }


                  Checkbox(
                      ....
                      value: parentvalue,
                      onChanged: update(),
                      ....
                    ),
```

> ERROR: A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.

=================================================================
UPDATE:

```
Checkbox(
          tristate: true,
          checkColor: Colors.white,
          fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
          value: isChecked,
          onChanged: (bool? value) {
            setState(() {
              isChecked = value!;
            });
          },
        ),
```

> ERROR: Null check operator used on a null value

if  i remove null check

```
onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  isChecked = value;
                });
              },
```

> ERROR: The argument type 'void Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'.

Comment: `value` is definitely has type of nullable boolean https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html

Comment: Did you edit the source code? try `flutter upgrade`

Comment: What is `isChecked` initially in your updated example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `tristate: true` in order to accept null. Also, the `update()` method needed to be changed because it provides nullable `bool` on callback.

```dart
Checkbox(
  tristate: true,
  value: parentvalue,
  onChanged: update,
  // onChanged:(value) { update(); },
),
```

And update method will be

```dart
 void update(value) {
    parentvalue = value;
    setState(() {});
  }
```

More about [`Checkbox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html) on flutter.dev.

Comment: already set tristate as true but still not working

Comment: Did you also check my updated `update` method? Also there is no `setState` have been called on your update method.

Comment: still not working....

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. If it fails, include full widget [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with setting `tristate` to `true`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            MyCheckbox(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCheckbox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCheckbox> createState() => _MyCheckboxState();
}

class _MyCheckboxState extends State<MyCheckbox> {
  bool? parentValue;
  void update() {
    setState(() {
      parentValue = null;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
        tristate: true,
        value: parentValue,
        onChanged: (_) {
          update();
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tristate property used for pass null value to checkbox as place of boolean
so if you want to pass null value to checkbox without showing any error then you have to set `true` value to the property of checkbox named `tristate`
like this

```
CheckBox(
....
tristate:true,
value:null,
...),
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's discuss how Null safety works.

If you expecting a value(variable/object) that shouldn't be null then simply make that value null safety. In your case
`bool? parentvalue` .

& if you read Checkbox property

```
/// This property must not be null.
  final bool? value;


/// If tristate is false (the default), [value] must not be null.
  final bool tristate;
```

here value is null safety & you cannot assign null value on it.

so if you assign your parentvalue null this will be not accepted by, Checkbox **value** property. it only except Boolean(true/false).

```
 void update() {
    //Wrong
    parentvalue = null;
  }
```

So either you should make your parentvalue by default true or false as per requirements. or you can also use `value: parentvalue??false/true` to maintain null safety.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use var instead of bool? and you will get all three states of check box i.e. true, false and null.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            MyCheckbox(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCheckbox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCheckbox> createState() => _MyCheckboxState();
}

class _MyCheckboxState extends State<MyCheckbox> {
  var parentValue;
  void update(var value) {
    setState(() {
      parentValue = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
        tristate: true,
        value: parentValue,
        onChanged: (value) {
          update(value);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add why changing bool? to var would help?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

the value of Checkbox must be nut null
if you want to Checkbox be unChecked when value is null you can use this instead of null check

```
value: parentvalue??false
```